# Debian9 - Upgrade virtaulbox fails on 'Cannot unload module vboxdrv.'

Tags: virtualbox, upgrade

I'm trying to update debian 9 and virtualbox can't be upgrated...
I'm getting the error:

```
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Cannot unload module vboxdrv.
```

Does anybody has any idea ?

```
$ apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  virtualbox-5.1
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/66.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 6,144 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Reading changelogs... Done
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 261193 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-5.1_5.1.36-122089~Debian~stretch_amd64.deb ...
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.36-122089~Debian~stretch_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 1
A copy of VirtualBox is currently running.  Please close it and try again.
Please note that it can take up to ten seconds for VirtualBox to finish running.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxdrv.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxdrv.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxballoonctrl-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxballoonctrl-service.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxautostart-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxautostart-service.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/vboxweb-service.service → /lib/systemd/system/vboxweb-service.service.
vboxdrv.sh: failed: Cannot unload module vboxdrv.

There were problems setting up VirtualBox.  To re-start the set-up process, run
  /sbin/vboxconfig
as root.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.36-122089~Debian~stretch_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seen in the error messages you posted:

```
A copy of VirtualBox is currently running.  Please close it and try again.
Please note that it can take up to ten seconds for VirtualBox to finish running.
```

Did you try that ?

Comment: Yes I tried that but it was still running on the background due some headless VMs.... the solution was to shut down all the VMs and close VirtualBox. Now all is working

Comment: You probably only closed VirtualBox's GUI, which won't stop headless VMs. The error message is indeed a bit misleading in that regard.